# Keep TextExpander from inserting text in the wrong spot?

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcuts, textexpander

Sometimes after I've been using TextExpander for a while I will type a snippet's shortcode, and it will insert the snippet in the wrong place. For example, I have a snippet to insert the php tags when I type `pphp`. When it works normally this is the outcome:

**Correct**

```
Last sentence was here. I'll press return, and at the
newline I will type pphp, which does this:
<?php 

?>
```

But when TextExpander starts acting up, then that same paragraph will end up looking like this:

**Incorrect**

```
Last sentence was here. I'll press return, and at the
newline I 
<?php 

?>
will type pphp, which does this:
```

If I relaunch the program it starts working fine again.

These are the preferences I have set. I've tried it both with and without the clipboard option and it does not seem to have an effect.

[image]

Has anyone else had his problem and found a solution? I think even back in version 2 it would do this and I was hoping that when v3 came out it would have been fixed, but I've been suffering for a while now. I don't believe I have any other programs interfering with it.

Comment: Contact their support. It's a commercial application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I switched over to Typinator and the same thing was happening. So, the problem appears to be Google Chrome / Chromium.

I haven't switched back to TextExpander, but the newest versions of Safari and Firefox are working fine with Typinator, and also the newest version of Google Chrome (beta) - but not Chromium, unfortunately.